# how to change the target frame link in jquery?

Tags: jquery, frame

i have two frame in my whole website. a frame with navigation bar and another frame with main content. when i click on a link, I want the other frame (content frame) to fade in and out, how would I accomplish this? I tried following jquery code. but it made the navigation frame fade in and out. what i mean is i put this code  in the navigation bar frame page, so when i click on navigation bar frame this frame is running the code, so this frame page is fading in or out. how can  redirect the content to the another frame? what is the command in jquery to change the target of the link?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("Body").css("display", "none");

    $("Body").fadeIn(2000);

 $("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  linkLocation = this.href;

  $("Body").fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);  
 });

 function redirectPage() {
  window.location = linkLocation;
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you main frame is called `frame_main`:

For your first question change the context of your body selector, e.g.

```
$("body", top.frames["frame_main"].document).fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);
```

And the second question, rather than `window.location` you have to use `top.frames["frameName"].location`.

```
function redirectPage() {
    top.frames["frame_main"].location = linkLocation;
}
```

**Edit**: Full example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var body = $("body", top.frames["frame_main"].document);

    body.css("display", "none").fadeIn(2000);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;

        body.fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);  
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        top.frames["frame_main"].location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: fade in is working , but fade out not working. can u tell me the detail of this process about where and what code shud be placed? so that i can figure out whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you update all your body selectors? I've updated my answer to show a complete answer, with the body selector executed just once.

Comment: thanx a lot man, it worked, i didnt updated the fade out body. this was the  first time i was seeking online help, and i got it. greatful to u.:)

Comment: hey, spolto, as i said it worked, now i want it to apply in case of external link. that is when i click on my menu in the navigation bar frame, the mainFrame (content frame) shud bring the page of the external link. now my problem is, when i click any menu item which is linked to a page from our domain is working with this fade in fade out. but in case of the external link as we are not using any extra page to be loaded on the main frame , rather just the link is loaded on the mainFrame, so this linked contents are not fading. do u have any idea how to do this? or u need more detail?

Comment: @fozlu: It's best if you mark this question as answered and create a new question for your new question - it's a pain working in these comments.

Comment: i cant mark answer as i dont have enough  reputation.though i have posted the new question

Comment: I think you should be able to click on the tick outline, you just can't *upvote* yet. I'm thinking about your other question...