# Close dialog and redirect if url present

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I added a css class to a link, that when clicked in closes the jquery ui dialog, but I want it to redirect to a page (in a iframe) and also close the dialog.

Currently, if the link has a href value, it just redirects and doesn't close the dialog.  If there is no href value, it closes the dialog as required.

```
<a href="http://...." class="button hide" target="contentFrame">Some Text</a>


$(".hide").bind("click", function(){
  $(".dialog").dialog('close');
});
```

So I need to somehow perform the closing of the dialog first, and then the redirect.

Can i override the click and do that somehow?
If there is no href value, or its empty, I don't need to redirect just close the dialog.

Comment: Are you  preforming the redirect from a dialog button handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually redirect after closing the dialog box (so you can control the order).  Something along the lines of:

```
$(".hide").bind("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".dialog").dialog('close');
  $iframe.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
})
```

remember that you'll have to `preventDefault()` or the link will click like normal.  See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for examples and more information.

Comment: note that the link is to redirect a specific frame, will yours work?

Comment: Updated so it will - for more information [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery).

Comment: also see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358660/how-to-change-the-target-frame-link-in-jquery

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$(".hide").bind("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".dialog").dialog('close');
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

to redirect. Put that after your dialog close line.